# Outliner : show objects match name with wildcards

Tags: outliner

I have 20 storeys building, each floor has its own objects, for example

floor 1 : Floor 1 bath, Floor 1 kitchen etc.

floor 2 : Floor 2 utility, Floor 2 terrace etc

up to ..

floor 20 : Floor 20 office, Floor 20 meeting etc.

I want to show objects starts with 'Floor 1' , 'Floor 3', 'Floor 12', 'Floor 13' , 'Floor 14' but not starts with other 'Floor XXX' .

I want to display the list in the outliner. Can i do this ?

Comment: what is the purpose of this?

Comment: I just want to do cross checking between blender and unity . I want  to see what 'floor' object exist in blender scene to match into unity.  I'm checking floor1 , 3 and 12 ,13,14 and i want to skip floor 2,4,5,....11 . If i just type 'floor ' then there will be too many object in the list so needs me to scroll a lot.  Or I have to check per floor. (floor 1 , floor 2, floor 12 ) .. this is the closest i can do.

Comment: Maybe create a temporary collection linking them all and remove the unwanted one from it?

Comment: Thanks, i just found the answer using regex by typing : floor [1,3,12-14] . Check my answer below.

Comment: Great, I didn't know that...

Comment: Thanks , and  you need 2.9 , not working in 2.8 ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution (only for 2.9 above , not working in 2.8 ) , the search box in outliner can accept regex (unix regex) pattern.

```
floor [1,3,12-14]
```

1,3 -> to match floor 1, floor 3

12-14 -> match range between 12 to 14 -> floor 12 , floor 13, floor 14

and will skip other number outside the range 1,3,12-14

We can also use ^ to exclude ( '^' means 'NOT') . For example if we type 'Floor [^143]', it will show everything starts with 'Floor ' but NOT starts with 'Floor 1' , 'Floor 4' and 'Floor 3'.

Comment: What about "floor [^2]" ?

Comment: Yes, works fine, it's just i didn't give enough detail about the case. Not only want to exclude floor 2 .  I 've just edited my post to clarify the goal. Btw i will include the ^ in the answer. Thanks for the additional info.